How to delete a directory whose name has special characters
My ./imap directory contains two folders with names containing special characters :
‘No’$‘\351’‘.sbd’
‘S’$‘\351’‘gol’$‘\350’‘ne.sbd’
(these are the full names with no other characters added).
The directory I am working in contains only these two files, so the following would be fine:
 rm -rf *
but it does nothing and returns no information
and
 rmdir *
returns
rmdir: unable to delete ‘No’$‘\351’‘.sbd’: Invalid argument
rmdir: unable to delete ‘S’$‘\351’‘gol’$‘\350’‘ne.sbd’: Invalid argument

How can I delete these two directories?
Edition. I add a photo of my screen to show the actual characters appearing without ambiguity.


What filesystem type are the files stored on? (I'm wondering if it's NTFS.)

I do not even know (I am just a user without root permission on thie server). However (if the following has a meaning)
stat -f -c %T /
returns
ext2/ext3

thoses name resolv to Noé and Ségolène, what is the result of stat -f -c %T .imap ? On a side note, can't you use your imap client to delete thoses directories/folders ?

stat -f -c %T .imap returns nfs.
I am working remotely and so do not know how to open my imap client (I have not used pine for quite a long time now...)
The resolution you gave (Noé and Ségolène) make perfect sens, however rm -rf Noé.sbd does nothing

rm -rf * | ls -l makes no sense, it says to direct the standard output of rm to the input of ls, but rm doesn't print anything to stdout, and ls doesn't read any input...

OK, thanks. I just wanted a one line command to 1) apply rm 2) show that it did nothing. I changed the picture accordingly to you comment.

Based on the fact that this is an NFS-mounted directory, my guess is that there's a mismatch between the ownership presented to the NFS client (what you see in the output of ls -l) and the ownership on the NFS server. You don't have permission to delete those directories on the NFS server. You will solve this the fastest by contacting whoever manages the NFS server and asking them to remove the directories for you.  It is unlikely that it has anything to do with "special characters" (unless the permissions/ownership were messed up on the server when someone tried to bulk modify things).

indeed. "Invalid argument" sounds a bit abnormal for rm. Also note that rm * gives the same error for the same files, so it's not a question of passing the filename to rm.

The obvious solution is to copy and paste from the terminal, enclosing the names in single quotes, but I'm guessing that the \3xx sequence is not a literal string of four characters but the terminals best attempt at rendering a single character from the name.
While this is neither neat, nor completely precise, I would just substitute wildcards for the non-ascii characters and escape the $. Assuming the open/close UTF single quotes are also part of the filename....
rmdir ?No?\$????.sbd?
rmdir ?S?\$????gol?\$????ne.sbd?

(you might want to test this with something non-destructuve first, like ls)

I suspect that won't work since the ‘ and ’ are unicode and not matched by a single ?

Wouldn't the rm -rf * attempt have taken these down already?

I had tried the copy-paste (could have said it, sorry!) with no success
rmdir 'No'$'\351''.sbd'
returns
rmdir: impossible de supprimer 'No'$'\351''.sbd': Argument invalide

And rmdir ?No?\$????.sbd?
returns
rmdir: impossible de supprimer '?No?$????.sbd?': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
(impossible to delete... no file of this type)

@terdon, ? matches a single unicode here (bash 5.4.1). @Josef: Not what I suggested - an ASCII single quote is treated as a special character in most shells (including bash). And I see someone has subsequently updated your post - but its still not clear what the characters are on your filesystem vs the characters visible here. How did the person whom edited it know?

I edited and I simply added code formatting to the post, I didn't change the content. Those were the original quotes and exactly why I don't think your solution will work.

The conversion in and out of markdown changes the content - so can copying from a terminal emulator and pasting into a browser. I don't know my solution will work because I don't have the data to test it on. Bash will match a multibyte character with a single '?' but I do expect it may take the OP more effort than just copy and paste - but anyone who blindly copies and pastes stuff from the internet will get their just desserts.

I deeply appreciate your efforts. I added a picture to my original post to remove ambiguities pin the characters involved.

In the screenshot, the quotes look a lot like ASCII single quotes. (They're straight, while the fancy ones are often slightly curver or diagonal.) That output from ls is likely quoted in a shell-compatible way, so it could be used as input to the shell as-is (with the outer quotes and all)

Thank you. If you mean just copy-pasting the name returned by ls as an argument of rm, then it does not work neither: rm consider the copy-pasted argument as an invalid argument (I changed again the picture to show my try and the result)

The other thing you might try is typing the first part of the name (with wildcard placeholders) then pressing tab to see if the shell can work out how to write the filenames, e.g. ls -ld ?No[tab] or use mc or similar to select the file from a list rather than having to type the name.

Thank you for the tab proposition. I add try this. If it usually work with "usual" characters, in this context, the tab leads to no proposition or completion.
